# Intellij Idea showing error when running the following program :-

Tags: java, methods

I am learning Java and was practicing coding. But when I run the following code :

```
public class Main {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        ToMilesPerHour(1.5);
        System.out.println(ToMilesPerHour(1.5));
    }

    public static long ToMilesPerHour(double kilometresperhour){
        if(kilometresperhour<0){
            return -1;
        } else if(kilometresperhour>0){
           long miles= (long) (kilometresperhour*0.609);
            StrictMath.round(miles);
            return miles;
        }
            return 0;
    }
}
```

It Shows this error :

```
Main method not found in class com.company.Main, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

How should I fix this ?

Comment: Check the "Main" method. It should be `main`, in lower case

Comment: did it but still showing the same error

Comment: I changed a few codes but instead of converting it is just showing the result as 0

Comment: work through a tutorial on java basics

Comment: Are you writing a JavaFX application (i.e. one using that API as GUI)? If not just ignore that part; Other than the last line of the error this question seems completely unrelated to JavaFX.

Comment: Btw any reason to use `StrictMath` instead of `Math`?

Answer (score 1):

Change `Main` to `main`. Also, you are converting double value to long, so 0.9135 is rounded to floor 0. It is expected behavior. If you give 12.5 as parameter for instance, result 7.6125 is rounded to floor 7 for using long. Therefore extra rounding is unnecessary.

Comment: `StrictMath.round` rounds to the closest long, i.e. `7.6125` would yield `8`, not `7`. Good work identifying the rounding as an issue, but I don't think the suggested solution would yield the desired result. Instead I assume the local `miles` variable should be made a `double` and the rounding should be removed from the rhs of the initialisation assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Java is case-sensitive. "Main" is not the same as "main". Use `public static void main(String[] args)` Also, you should use camelCase instead of PascalCase when writing method names (unless it's a constructor).